# GitHub API returns empty array, while credentials are provided

Tags: github-api

We have a shell script to automate some of our GitHub tasks related to repos in our organization.

Our script calls API this way:

```
curl --silent -H 'Authorization: token some_github_api_token' 'https://api.github.com/orgs/OurOrgName/repos?per_page=100'
```

Yet it returns an empty array `[]`. I checked this URL in my chrome browser where I'm logged into the GitHub:

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/OurOrgName/repos
```

And it still returned an empty array.

What could be wrong? Why do we not get the list of our repos?